# Are there plans to expand Super User to include languages other than English?

Tags: feature-request, superuser, languages, internationalization

I'd like to ask if there are any plans on expanding [Super User](https://superuser.com/) to include more languages? Sometimes it is hard for someone like me who isn't a native English speaker to explain what is happening, and it would be much easier if I had a translated version of Super User to use.

If there are any plans, is there anything that the community can do to help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use a democratic method of creating new sites - [you can propose](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology) a new site on [area51.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com), the site that tracks the progress of new site proposals.

> it would be much easier if I had a translated version of Superuser to use.

Well, there's always [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) - it can do whole pages too ;)

Comment: The matter is not about being translated or not... But having all the people I ask talking the same mother-language as me makes evertyhing easier. It is easy for me to explain and it'll be easy for them to understand. I guess that I expressed myself bad about this, sorry! I'll take a look at area51, thanks! :)

Comment: @Undo very funny. You didn't understand what the OP asked for :-) Not a new site, a translation option. Many global sites using a content management system have translations site.com/es/xyz style. SE cpuld support dual language entry English + native language. Native language speakers could filter via that language